# An error when serializing a list of validationattribute

Tags: validation, serialization, xml-serialization, data-annotations, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a list of (ValidationAttribute) as shown below:

```
RequiredAttribute tRequired = new RequiredAttribute();
List<ValidationAttribute> ValidationList = new List<ValidationAttribute>();

ValidationList.Add(tRequired);

XmlSerializer tXMLSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ValidationAttribute>));
MemoryStream tMemStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter tStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(tMemStream);

tXMLSerializer.Serialize(tStreamWriter, ValidationList);
```

When the (Serialize) function execute, the following exception will be thrown:

```
The type System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I needed to pass the type of (RequiredAttribute) to the XMLSerializer:

```
RequiredAttribute tRequired = new RequiredAttribute();
List<ValidationAttribute> ValidationList = new List<ValidationAttribute>();

ValidationList.Add(tRequired);

Type[] tExtraTypes = new Type[] { typeof(RequiredAttribute) };

XmlSerializer tXMLSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ValidationAttribute>),tExtraTypes );
```